# Approve a yaml pipeline deployment in Azure DevOps using REST api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the new multi-stage pipelines in Azure DevOps to manage deployments to Azure environments.
I setup the corresponding **Environments** in Azure DevOps so that we can explicitly approve the actual deployments for each system.

We want to provide a custom web view to *monitor the deployments and approve them*.
I couldn't find any online docs for the **REST api** of the new pipelines and environments.
So far I can only trigger the releases but I need to approve the deployments from the Azure DevOps portal.

Any doc, blog post or example available?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262291/14413668 You can refer to this post, we found a working answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Approve a yaml pipeline deployment in Azure DevOps using REST api is not supported.

As we can see by pressing F12 in browser when approving a deployment, it has the different `"approvalId":"8ca00a75-de34-43c0-83b9-702dd1aae775"`every time for the same environment.

You can suggest the feature from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Hi all,
its almost been 2 years now, has this feature now been enabled for YAML pipelines or still YAML pipelines cannot be programmatically approved? Any comments from AZ DevOps experts on this. @andy-li-msft

Comment: there's something here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1