# Azure Pipelines: Bulk approve of deployments to environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to approve runs via the CLI or the API (or anything else)? I'm looking for a way to bulk approve multiple runs from different pipelines but it's not available in the UI.

Let's say I have 100 pipelines that have a deployment job to a production environment. I would like to approve all awaiting for approval runs.

Currently, I cannot find something like it in the docs of the Azure DevOps REST API or the CLI.

The feature docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals

The following question is related but I'm looking for any way of solving it but not just via API:
[Approve a yaml pipeline deployment in Azure DevOps using REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171325/approve-a-yaml-pipeline-deployment-in-azure-devops-using-rest-api)

Comment: Are you using Multi-stage pipeline? Or your deployment job is configured with UI?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Multi-stage pipeline via YAML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What jessehouwing's guess is correct. Now multi-stage still be in preview, and the corresponding SDK/API/extension hasn't been expanded and provided to public.

You may think that what about not using API. I have checked the corresponding code from our backend, all of operations to `multi-stage approval` contain one required parameter: `approvalId`. I'm sure you have known that this value is **unique** and different approval map with different `approvalId` value. This means, no matter which method you want to try with, `approvalId` is the big trouble. And based on my known, until now, there's no any api/SDK, third tool or extension can achieve this value **directly**.

---

In addition, for `multi-stage` YAML, its release process logic is not same with the release that defined with UI. So, all of public APIs which can work with release(UI), are not suitable with the release of multi-stage.

We have one undisclosed api, can get `Approval` message of multi-stage:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals/{approvalId}
```

You can try with listing approval without specifying `approvalId`: `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals`. And its response message: `Query for approvals failed. A minimum of one query parameter is required.\r\nParameter name: queryParameters.` This represents you must tell system the specified `approval`(the big trouble I mentioned previously).

In fact, for why `approvalId` is a necessary part, it is caused from our backend code structure. I'd suggest you raise suggestion on developing API/SDK for multi-stage [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft thank you for the reply! I've posted a suggestion https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/920135/azure-devops-api-support-getting-list-of-pending-a.html. Turns out that the people asking this for a while already https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/823239/show-pending-aprovals-in-environments.html. I wonder what's your current idea of covering the microservices scenario. Is Azure Pipelines designed for that and am I just using it wrongly?

Comment: @ebashmakov I don’t you are doing wrong. No mater for mine, or our team recommendation, multi-stage is more suitable for microservices CI/CD than UI, because multi-stage has can make use of `environment`. That’s what the advantage of `environment`(only for multi-stage). Though traditional UI has completed feature, but for microservices, its applied will be more complexed.

Comment: @ebashmakov Last year, our main develop task is YAML syntax and features expand. Sure we will keep the relevant services (API/SDK) updated as soon as possible.

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft thanks for the clarification. Looking forward to the new updates!

Comment: @ebashmakov. Welcome! This should be what we need to do:-) In addition, appreciate you could accept one of these 2 answers so that others who is looking for similar feature could directly find it.

Answer (score 16):

I was just searching for an answer for this regarding getting the approval id that you would need. In fact there is an undocumented API to approve an approval check.

This is as Merlin explain the following

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals/{approvalId}
```

The body has to look like this

```
[{
    "approvalId": "{approvalId}",
    "status": {approvalStatus},
    "comment": ""
}]
```

where `{approvalStatus}` is telling the API if you approved or not. You probly have to try, but I had a `4` as a status. I guess there are only 2 possibilities. Either for "approved" or "denied".

The question is now how you get the approval ID? I found it. You get it by using the timeline API of a classic build. The [build API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) says that you get it by the following

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1
```

the build timeline you get in the response of the build run, but it has a pattern which is

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/Timeline?api-version=5.1
```

Besides a flat array container a parent / child rleationship from stage, phase, job and tasks, you can find within it something like the following:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "previousAttempts": [
        
      ],
      "id": "95f5837e-769d-5a92-9ecb-0e7edb3ac322",
      "parentId": "9e7965a8-d99d-5b8f-b47b-3ee7c58a5b1c",
      "type": "Checkpoint",
      "name": "Checkpoint",
      "startTime": "2020-08-14T13:44:03.05Z",
      "finishTime": null,
      "currentOperation": null,
      "percentComplete": null,
      "state": "inProgress",
      "result": null,
      "resultCode": null,
      "changeId": 73,
      "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "workerName": null,
      "details": null,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "url": null,
      "log": null,
      "task": null,
      "attempt": 1,
      "identifier": "Checkpoint"
    },
    {
      "previousAttempts": [
        
      ],
      "id": "9e7965a8-d99d-5b8f-b47b-3ee7c58a5b1c",
      "parentId": null,
      "type": "Stage",
      "name": "Power Platform Test (orgf92be262)",
      "startTime": null,
      "finishTime": null,
      "currentOperation": null,
      "percentComplete": null,
      "state": "pending",
      "result": null,
      "resultCode": null,
      "changeId": 1,
      "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "workerName": null,
      "order": 2,
      "details": null,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "url": null,
      "log": null,
      "task": null,
      "attempt": 1,
      "identifier": "Import_Test"
    },
    {
      "previousAttempts": [
        
      ],
      "id": "e54149c5-b5a7-4b82-8468-56ad493224b5",
      "parentId": "95f5837e-769d-5a92-9ecb-0e7edb3ac322",
      "type": "Checkpoint.Approval",
      "name": "Checkpoint.Approval",
      "startTime": "2020-08-14T13:44:03.02Z",
      "finishTime": null,
      "currentOperation": null,
      "percentComplete": null,
      "state": "inProgress",
      "result": null,
      "resultCode": null,
      "changeId": 72,
      "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "workerName": null,
      "details": null,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "url": null,
      "log": null,
      "task": null,
      "attempt": 1,
      "identifier": "e54149c5-b5a7-4b82-8468-56ad493224b5"
    }
  ],
  "lastChangedBy": "00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000",
  "lastChangedOn": "2020-08-14T13:44:03.057Z",
  "id": "86fb4204-9c5e-4e72-bdb1-eefe230480ec",
  "changeId": 73,
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/***"
}
```

below you can see a step that is called "Checkpoint.Approval". The id of that step **IS** the approval Id you need to approve everything. If you want to know from which stage the approval is, then you can follow up the parentIds until the parentId property is `null`.
This will then be the stage.

With this you can successfully get the approval id and use it to approve with the said

Comment: Thank you so much, what a lifesaver!

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that Sebastian's answer worked for me, even in Azure DevOps 2020 on-prem.
After retrieving the **approvalId** from either methods used above (I was specifically using a service hook for my integration), I used the following API **PATCH** call:

> [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals/?api-version=6.0-preview](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/approvals/?api-version=6.0-preview)

and in the body:

```
[
    {
        "approvalId": "{approvalId}",
        "status": {status integer}, (4 - approved; 8 - rejected)
        "comment": ""
    }
]
```

The call is passed with the application/json Content-Type, but in some situations it did not like that I was using the [] brackets, so you will need to work around that, only then will the call work.
I was even able to integrate this call into my custom connector in MS **Power Automate**

Answer (score 3):

I added support to the latest version of the [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/4.0.13) Powershell module to support bulk pipeline approvals.

Code snippet without using the AzurePipelinesPS sessions

```
$instance = 'https://dev.azure.com'
$collection = 'your_project'
$project = 'your_project'
$apiVersion = '5.1-preview'
$securePat = 'your_personal_access_token' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText 
Get-APPipelinePendingApprovalList -Instance $instance -Collection $collection -Project $project -PersonalAccessToken $securePat -ApiVersion $apiVersion | Out-GridView -Passthru | % { Update-APPipelineApproval -Instance $instance -Collection $collection -Project $project -PersonalAccessToken $securePat -ApiVersion $apiVersion -ApprovalId $PSitem.approvalId -status 'approved'}
```

Code snippet with AzurePipelinesPS sessions

```
$session = 'your_session'
Get-APPipelinePendingApprovalList $session | Out-GridView -Passthru | % { Update-APPipelineApproval $session -ApprovalId $PSitem.approvalId -status 'approved'}
```

See the [AzurePipelinesPS project page](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS#creating-a-session) for details on secure session handling.

### Function Definitions used in the code above

#### Get-APPipelinePendingApprovalList

1. Loops through pipeline build runs with the status of 'notStarted' or 'inProgress' in a project. This build lookup supports filters like pipeline definition ids or a source branch name.
2. For each build it then looks up the timeline record where the approval id, the stage name and the stage identifier are found.
3. Optionally with the ExpandApproval switch it can expand each approval with details

The object returned from this function contains the following properties, the values have been mocked

```
pipelineDefinitionName : MyPipeline
pipelineDefinitionId   : 100
pipelineRunId          : 2001
pipelineUrl            : https://dev.azure.com/your_project/_build/results?
sourceBranch           : refs/heads/master
stageName              : Prod Deployment
stageIdentifier        : Prod_Deployment
approvalId             : xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
```

#### Out-GridView

Displays data in a Grid View where the results can be filtered, ordered and selected.

#### %

The percent sign is shorthand for Foreach-Object

#### Update-APPipelineApproval

Updates the status of an approval to approved or rejected.

### Credit

Thanks to Sebastian Schütze for cracking the timeline part!

Answer (score 1):

The `az pipelines` extension doesn't suport approvals yet, I suppose due to the fact that multi-stage pipelines are still in preview and the old release hub will eventually be replaced by it.

But [there is a REST API you can use to list and update approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). These can be called from PowerShell with relative ease.

Or use the [`vsteam` powershell module](https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam/tree/master/docs) and `Get-VSTeamApproval` and `Set-VSTeamApproval`.

Comment: I checked the doc before and my impression was that it's about "old" releases and it's not related to the new checks/approvals in the pipelines. So I tried it this time and it returns 0 approvals which is correct since I don't use "Releases"

Comment: No problem! The REST apis for the new one aren't doc'ed yet. But using fiddler should get you the stuff you need...

Comment: if only I knew which endpoint to call. I tried `GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/approval/approvals` but it returns 404