# Is there a corresponding Azure DevOps REST Api for ManualValidation task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

[ManualValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines) task was introduced for the YAML pipeline.

Anyone aware if there is a corresponding REST API for that?

I can see there is a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/manual-interventions?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) dedicated for ManualInterventions but that was more for the classic release pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigated the REST API call via the UI.. it actually uses the same [Approvals and Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API

Hence, it will be very similar approach as discussed here [Azure Pipelines: Bulk approve of deployments to environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133259/azure-pipelines-bulk-approve-of-deployments-to-environments) where we can use the build/timeline REST API to retrieve the identifier and the post via the Approvals REST API